No connection between local devices and devices on VPN subnet
I configured VPN on my home router (OpenVPN protocol). The goal is to VPN into my home local network and access my home desktop from a remote device (my laptop).
I successfully established VPN connection from the remote laptop. I can see the connected laptop in the router's settings page and the remote laptop has access to the Internet with the public IP of my home network. I can successfully ping my home router from this remote laptop and access the router's settings page by it's local IP (192.168.1.1).
Problem: I cannot ping my home desktop from the remote laptop and vice verca, i.e. my local devices and the devices on the VPN subnet cannot talk to each other. Moreover I cannot ping the remote laptop from the router by the laptop's IP in the VPN subnet.
I checked that IP addresses on the remote LAN which my laptop is connected to (192.168.163.x), the VPN subnet (192.168.10.x) and my home LAN which my desktop is connected to (192.168.1.x) do not overlap.
The strange thing (as it seems to me) is that ipconfig on my remote laptop says that it's IP on the VPN subnet is 192.168.10.6 with the subnet mask 255.255.255.252, while the VPN subnet is configured to be 192.168.10.0/255.255.255.0. But I have no idea if this is the problem and how to fix it.
The remote laptop is connected to the Internet via the hotspot on my smartphone (do not know if this is important or not).
I am new to networking and need help investigating the issue further.

Are your desktop and laptop's firewalls (wf.msc → ICMP Echo Request) configured to allow pings from outside of their subnet? Does Wireshark on both devices show them receiving ping requests (regardless of whether they reply or not)?

@grawity_u1686, thanks! I allowed Echo Request ICMPv4 in Windows firewall on the remote laptop for the IP addresses from my home LAN and from the VPN subnet and everything started to work as expected. I assumed it might be the firewall but was intimidated by the firewall settings and not knowing what to change without messing things up. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.
